# Free FFT library for ARM CPU

Tags: library, c++, c, math, arm

I need a FFT library for ARM platforms, especially in Apple M1 and Androids. I have already browsed some, but none meets my requirement:

- **FFTS** has stopped development, and its assembly code do not compile in newer armv8a.
- **FFTW** is not free for commercial use.
- **KissFFT** is not optimized, actually it is almost exactly 4-times slower than FFTS.
- **CMSIS** is rather large and complicated system. I still don't know how to make it work.
- **vDSP** is Apple-specific.
- I'm trying on ARM **ComputeLibrary**. But it would be better if there's a smaller library.

I'm using C and C++.

If there's no one, I have to try to write some.